# Is using virtual method have only advantage of single instance generation?

Tags: c#, oop, virtual

I have learnt that the usage of virtual methods provide a default behaviour for a method/function. My query is that, when we can implement a method of same name (as in base class) using "new" in derived class and can call it by objects separately then whats the use of virtual method. For instance;

```
class A
{
      public void F()
      {
         //default behavior
      }

      public virtual void G()
      {
         //default behavior
      }
}

class B:A
{
    new public void F()
     {
       //new behavior from that of class A
     }
    public override void G()
     {
      //new behavior from that of class A
     }
}

class Test
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
       //For calling A's method use same compile time and run time object
       A obj1 = new A();

       //For calling B's method use compile time object of A and run time of B
       A obj2 = new B();

       obj1.F(); //O/P is A's method result
       obj2.F(); //O/P is A's method result
       obj1.G(); //O/P is A's method result
       obj2.G(); //O/P is B's method result
}
```

My question is why virtual G() in class A is needed when we can provide default behavior as well as derived behavior by using same compile time object and run time object of both classes A and B as like:

```
A obj1 = new A(); //for calling A's methods
B obj2 = new B(); //for calling B's methods
A obj3 = new B(); //for having default behavior of class A using B's run time object.
```

What I fetched is only that in case of virtual we just don't need to make one more object of same compile and run time type. It can be achieved by a single object which is compile time of type A and run time of type B.

Answer (score 7):

> My question is why virtual G() in class A is needed when we can provide default behavior by using same compile time and run time object and derived behavior by using compile time object of A and run time of B.

Because then you can *only* use code which already knows about `B`. Half the point of polymorphism is allow you to write code which doesn't care about which subclass it actually works with.

For example, I can write a method to copy the contents of one stream to another using `Stream.Read` and `Stream.Write` precisely because they're virtual or abstract methods. It doesn't matter which implementations are passed in.

You should very rarely use `new` as a method modifier - if you really want to provide different behaviour for a non-virtual method, it's much clearer if you create a totally different method name, so that anyone reading the code understands this is a very separate method from the one declared in the base class.

Comment: Perhaps my mind is not settled by the reply...I am not able to get it clearly. Can you give it more realistic touch please and Yes thanks for prompt answer.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what you mean by "more realistic touch".

Comment: Well sorry not to be clear. I was trying to ask that: Is usage of virtual method just saves memory only? So as not to create more objects or it has different reasons too? By realistic touch I meant any real life example.

Comment: I've *given* a real life example - using the virtual methods is Stream. It's nothing to do with memory - it's all about abstraction.

Comment: But Mr. Jon as you said "It's nothing to do with memory".I feel using virtual method saves memory by putting down the need of creating more objects(same compile/run time type) & providing concept of default behavior/abstraction. I agree, making new methods for Read and Write is not worth & takes memory unnecessarily. We can override the Stream.Read/Write methods to save memory & provide the needed implementation. I conclude (up to now) that concept of virtual method saves memory and provide ease to understand code and nothing else which support the last paragraph of your root answer.

Comment: @user1740176: No, you've completely misunderstood the purpose of virtual methods and polymorphism in general. The point is that I can work with a `Stream` object with no idea of what the underlying implementation will do. I can call virtual methods, and the execution time type of the object will determine what the effect should be - so in the case of a `FileStream` it will write to the file system, for a `NetworkStream` it'll send some bytes over a network connection etc. This isn't really something which can be explained adequately in comments - I suggest you read up about polymorphism.

Comment: ok Thanks Jon for all...I will try to get into the subject. I m trying with example of overriding toString() method.

Answer (score 0):

Jon points out one reason another is that if you hide the implementation that is use new any reference to the method in the base class is to the base implementation whereas if you override any invocation even in the base class uses the overriding method

```
 protected virtual void Foo(){
 }

 private void Bar() {
     //do generic stuff
     Foo();
 }
```

If a class overrides foo then that will alter the effect of calling bar. This is the foundation of certain design patterns such as AbstractTemplate

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rune. Apologies, couldn't get your example.